# How to wrap Django FormPreview in a view

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a situation (shopping cart checkout sequence) where the workflow used in Django's FormPreview contrib app looks perfect, except I need to have some view logic occur before I call it (I can't call the checkout sequence if the cart is empty, for example). From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/), it looks like you call FormPreview directly from the urlconf like so:

```
(r'^post/$', SomeModelFormPreview(SomeModelForm))
```

...and it calls the overridden done() method for the FormPreview directly (without a view).

Since my urls.py is similar to:

```
url(r'^checkout/$', 'checkout', {'SSL': settings.ENABLE_SSL }, name = 'checkout'),
```

and my view is similar to:

```
def checkout(request):
    if cart.empty(request):
        cart = urlresolvers.reverse('shopping_cart')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        checkoutform = CheckoutFormPreview(CheckoutForm)
```

This last line is where I'd like to call it, but can't figure out how to wrap it... Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `CheckoutFormPreview(CheckoutForm)` returns a callable view that you can add to your url config. If you call it in your view, you just need to pass the required `request` argument. Then return the result.

Putting it together, you have (untested):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_preview_view = CheckoutFormPreview(CheckoutForm)
    return form_preview_view(request)
```